# Calculate the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{100} n^{2}(\frac{1}{2})^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I want to Calculate the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{100} n^{2}(\frac{1}{2})^n$$ .No idea on how to begin. im just starting to learn some basic discrete math.Im not interested just solving this example but on a more general way on how to calculate sums by seeing how this one is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:$$f(N,x):=\sum_{n=1}^Nx^n=x{1-x^{N}\over1-x}\\
\implies x{d\over dx}f(N,x)=\sum_{n=1}^Nnx^n\\
\implies x{d\over dx}\left(x{d\over dx}f(N,x)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^Nn^2x^n$$

Comment: why there is an $x$ on you firt sentence. i thought the geometric series converged only to  fraction you wrote not times $x$

Comment: i calculated to be 5.9 wolfram says the same thing only  i used ur first equation without the $x$. i multiplied my franction only on the derivatives!!

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis You don't need to worry about convergence as the sum has a finite number of terms i.e. it's not an infinite series.

Comment: the geometric series has a formula $\frac{1-x^N}{1-x}$ not $x\frac{1-x^N}{1-x}$ i get why you multiply with an x after you take the derivative but why before?

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Your formula for geometric series would hold if n started from 0 but here n starts from 1. After differentiation $x^n$ becomes $nx^{n-1}$. To restore the power of $x$ we multiply with $x$ after differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

Most sums cannot be summed explicitly. 
Typically, you might first look to see if it is a geometric series (sum is the same word) then it will have an explicit sum.

e.g $\sum_{n=0}^{N}x^n=\frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}$

Your sum is not of this form. The next thing you might try is to differentiate this expression to create powers of n multiplying the $x^n$ term. With a bit of algebra and differentiating twice you can make this work for your sum.
If each term can be written as a difference of two terms in the same sequence you can also find the sum

i.e. $\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n=\sum_{n=0}^{N}(b_{n+1}-b_n)=b_{N+1}-b_0$

After that you are struggling.
More often than not though you are not really interested in the value of any given finite sum - a computer will calculate it for you. More often than not you are interested in an estimate of an infinite sum or whether it has a sum at all (which a computer cannot, in general, deal with). Then, quite often, the sum in question is compared to the infinite geometric series or one of its derivatives.
In general I would suggest that you become very familiar with the geometric series and its derivatives. That will be very useful to you in the long run.

Comment: differentiate which expression? I mean both parts? Differentiating the series is like differentiating the inside with no problem?

Comment: Differentiate as shown in the first answer. Term by term differentiation is fine for a finite sum